# Why does the typescript not see class property

Tags: typescript

I can't figure out why Typescript doesn't see the class property in the loop. Example:

```
class FirstSettings {
  val=[1,2] as const
 ...
}

class SecondSettings {
  otherVal=[3,4] as const
  obj={
   params1: 1 as const,
   params2: 2 as const,
   ...
  }
 ...
}

class ThirdSettings {
  otherParams=[1,2] as const;
  obj={
   params1: 1 as const,
   params2: 2 as const,
   ...
  }
 ...
}


const mySettings = {} as FirstSettings & SecondSettings & ThirdSettings;
 ...only later do I have the ability to merge classes, so first an empty object
 
 mySettings.otherVal.filter(value => ...);
```

Here is where I have a problem. TS7006: Parameter 'value' implicitly has an 'any' type.
How to fix type mySettings so value type is visible?

There are a lot of settings and they are constantly supplemented, it is not an option to prescribe the type of each setting

Comment: I see the error: `Property 'filter' does not exist on type 'never'.
  The intersection 'readonly [3, 4] & readonly [1, 2]' was reduced to 'never' because property '0' has conflicting types in some constituents.`

Comment: See https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?noUncheckedIndexedAccess=true&target=99&module=100&noImplicitOverride=true&noPropertyAccessFromIndexSignature=true&exactOptionalPropertyTypes=true#code/MYGwhgzhAEBiCWAnCAXAygUxS+A7A5jAN4CwAUNNAG5ggC8A2gIwA0ATALrSTTAD2uVOQC+5cqEgxM-XABNM2PIWikK0PigAWGRADVajAMwsALFx4zULcpT4AjAFZ1VlaAAcwiMAFsITAFzQTNwwlijWau6ePhBsgWwhvAJWNtCiZOni4FDQACqaSPJYOATEqRraegbM7OahySjljs6pUV6+AUGJYRGuHu2x8d0NvWkiYmTiDdDeAJ4KJcp0KsKJCMjoxUowAGTQ0gJFiqXQe-mFC9sA3DY2c5elAHQVOvogjwBm8CAoOgAUNBAAFcMNA6AA+aCPaEASiuQA

Comment: mySettings.otherVal type (1|2)[] and there are no questions to the filter, there is a question why there is no type  in the filter itself

Comment: Because `otherVal` has two different non-overlapped types and in such cases the common type is `never`

Comment: Please provide a [mre] that clearly demonstrates the issue you are facing.  Ideally someone could paste the code into a standalone IDE like [The TypeScript Playground (link here!)](https://tsplay.dev/m35Lbw) and immediately get to work solving the problem without first needing to re-create it.  So there should be no pseudocode, typos, unrelated errors, or undeclared types or values.

Comment: There was a small mistake, sorry, corrected, everything works. But it didn't change the essence. I have dynamic import and mySettings  are collected from different files. I can't figure out why this is an error.

Comment: If I remove  '& SecondSettings & ThirdSettings'  and it will be const mySettings = {} as FirstSetting  then the types are visible ( mySettings.val.filter(value => value <-----visible type);
Apparently the problem is in the union type